# Lost of text color in ListBox on Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Width="230" MaxWidth="250"
          ItemsSource="{Binding FiltredOrders}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}"
          DisplayMemberPath="StringForListBox" Foreground="Black"
          FontWeight="Bold"
          FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
```

When I start a program on Win7, everything's OK. But when I start it on WinXP, the text in the ListBox has no color. What could cause this?

Target framework: .NET Framework 4

Comment: What do you mean no color? Is it the same color as the background meaning you cannot see it or does it actually gets transparent?

Comment: Text is invisible. It cannot be seen even when item is selected(blue background).

Comment: Is this a desktop app or a wpf browser app?

Comment: Is this problem reproduced when used in a trivial application (just Window+ListView)? If not, have you tried reducing the problem to a minimum reproducing example? I see no obvious problems in your code.

Comment: Is the property `StringForListBox` initialized with values? Have you tried another `FontFamily`?

Comment: Problem is in DisplayMemberPath. When I delet it all is work. But there is other problem, ListBox uses just ToString of my Class, but I need another text to print there.

Comment: You can use String.Format in XAMl to add addiotional text to binded info.

Comment: Solved by using of DataTemplate. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can try to solve this issue:

1. Check if the Win XP isn't missing any Windows or .NET updates.
2. Check what happens if you use another font. If a font is missing on a certain computer, Windows tries to use another similar font that he can find.

So according to me, this isn't a problem of color, but rather a mismatch in versioning or a font issue.